# Objects are not pushing in correct order to JSON object using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to push the objects to JSON object, before pushing the objects to JSON object, its displaying correctly, but when I see the JSON object, its returning the last iterated object. My code is following

```
  var result = {};
  for(var n = 0; n < finalSubSet.length; n++) {
    pushArrayToSlides(finalSubSet[n]);
    if(n == 2) break;
  }
  function pushArrayToSlides(arr) {
    for(var i in arr) {
      console.log($scope.slides[arr[i]]);
      result['image'+(i)] = $scope.slides[arr[i]];
    }
    console.log(result);
    first.push(result);
  }
```

Please check the console logs. 
The fiddle http://plnkr.co/edit/umswXrj8AgpK7T2dP9Pk?p=preview

Comment: keys in object are not ordered, Use array

Comment: @Satpal, yeah. But why is it so? Because of that all the images are duplicate in order. What is the fix for this one?

Comment: You could use an array and on every insert set a key with the name of the new object on a status object ... not very flexible but will work if you only want to add them once

Comment: @FabianN. Can you please provide a snippet?